# what protoc commande do in this line?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, caffe, openpose

i'm using this documentation  and i didn't get the step 4
https://medium.com/@alok.gandhi2002/build-openpose-with-without-gpu-support-for-macos-catalina-10-15-6-8fb936c9ab05#726f

i tried this

````
MacBook-Pro-de-admin:openpose admin$ protoc /Users/admin/openpose_build/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto --cpp_out=.
/Users/admin/openpose_build/openpose/3rdparty/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).```
````

Comment: You can't run a `proto` file. You're supposed to call `protoc`, exactly as the tutorial told you.

Comment: @tkausl i just paste the wrong text i've edit  it now